# Use specific alpha parameters for multiple elastic net in R

Tags: r, parameters, apply, glmnet, regularized

I'm trying to perform multiple elastic net simultaneously in R. I have a 10x15 matrix each column is called Xi e.g. X1,X2,...,X15 and perform elastic net in order to obtain the optimal `alpha` and `lambda`
parameters. Then i save the `alpha` values in a dataframe called `alphas` in my environment and looks like the following

```
alpha
1  0.001
2  0.000
3  0.000
4  0.064
5  0.729
6  0.729
7  1.000
8  0.001
9  0.000
10 0.000
11  0.001
12  0.000
13  0.000
14  0.064
15  0.729
```

My goal is to perform multiple `cv.glmnet` (one for each Xi) with the corresponding alpha i already found. e.g. use `alpha=0.001` for `cv.glmnet` model of Xi, etc. How can i replace the alpha value in the below code in order to use all the obtained alpha values?

```
data<-matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=10,ncol = 15)
colnames(data) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6","X7","X8","X9","X10","X11","X12","X13","X14","X15")
data #random data
library(glmnet)
library(coefplot)

A <- as.matrix(data)
set.seed(1234)
results <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) {
  list(
    cvfit = cv.glmnet(A[, -i] , A[, i] , standardize = TRUE , type.measure = "mse" , nfolds = 10 , alpha = 1)
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to do multiple sets, use the same sequence of column index to subset the alphas as the `length` of alphaset is the same as the number of columns of the `matrix` 'A'

```
alphaset  <- c( 0.001, 0, 0, 0.064, 0.729, 0.729, 1.0, 
           0.001, 0, 0, 0.001, 0, 0,  0.064, 0.729)
lst_out <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) {
  list(
     cvfit = cv.glmnet(A[, -i] , A[, i] , standardize = TRUE , 
      type.measure = "mse" , nfolds = 10 , alpha = alphaset[i])
    )
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `for` loop.

```
alpha <- c(0.001, 0.000, 0.000, 0.064, 0.729, 0.729, 1.000, 0.001, 0.000, 0.000, 0.001, 0.000, 0.000, 0.064, 0.729)

cvfit <- vector("list", length(alpha))
names(cvfit) <- paste0("cvfit for alpha=", alpha)

for(k in 1:length(alpha))
  for(i in 1:ncol(A))
    cvfit[[k]][[i]] <- list(cv.glmnet(A[, -i] , A[, i] , standardize = TRUE , type.measure = "mse" , nfolds = 10 , alpha = alpha[k]))
```